# Total Commander automatic FTP command sending on file copy

Tags: ftp, total-commander

I have an FTP server that requires an allocate ("ALLO filesize") command to be sent before each file copying. The file only should be copied if the allocation was succesful: received a "200 allocated ... bytes" message.

Is there any way to automatize and hide this operation, maybe with an existing plug-in or with a specific setting in Total Commander?